# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixtures' of undefined, Nested Json From Fetch Call

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-bootstrap, fetch-api

Not the best with asynchronous calls, JS or React and struggling with it... here goess..

So I am using `fetch` library to render a table from data that looks like this (there are more fixtures in the `fixtures` array:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 380,
        "fixtures": [{
            "fixture_id": 157015,
            "league_id": 524,
            "league": {
                "name": "Premier League",
                "country": "England",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/39.png",
                "flag": "https://media.api-sports.io/flags/gb.svg"
            },
            "event_date": "2019-08-09T19:00:00+00:00",
            "event_timestamp": 1565377200,
            "firstHalfStart": 1565377200,
            "secondHalfStart": 1565380800,
            "round": "Regular Season - 1",
            "status": "Match Finished",
            "statusShort": "FT",
            "elapsed": 90,
            "venue": "Anfield",
            "referee": "Michael Oliver, England",
            "homeTeam": {
                "team_id": 40,
                "team_name": "Liverpool",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/40.png"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "team_id": 71,
                "team_name": "Norwich",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/71.png"
            },
            "goalsHomeTeam": 4,
            "goalsAwayTeam": 1,
            "score": {
                "halftime": "4-0",
                "fulltime": "4-1",
                "extratime": null,
                "penalty": null
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is how I handle the async functions:

```
export async function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    let someResponse = response.json();
    console.log("loading response");
    console.log(someResponse);
    return someResponse;
  }

  if (response.status === 400) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }

  const error = await response.text();
  console.log("error was: " + error);
  console.log("status was: " + response.status);
  throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
}

export function handleError(error) {
  console.error("API call failed. " + error);
  throw error;
}
```

I'm using Flux framework so here's the flux action:

```
import dispatcher from "../appDispatcher";
import * as footballResultsApi from "../api/footballResultsApi";
import actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export function loadFixtures() {
  return footballResultsApi.getFixtures().then(fixtures => {
    dispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: actionTypes.LOAD_FIXTURES,
      fixtures: fixtures
    });
  });
}
```

And this is my code within a functional component to render the Fixtures Table:

```
const [fixtures, setFixtures] = useState(fixturesStore.getFixtures());

  useEffect(() => {
    fixturesStore.addChangeListener(onChange);

    if (fixturesStore.getFixtures().length === 0) loadFixtures();

    return () => {
      fixturesStore.removeChangeListener(onChange);
    };
  }, []);

  function onChange() {
    console.log("fixtures changed");
    setFixtures(fixturesStore.getFixtures());
  }


return (
    <GridWrapper>
      <div>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr className="same-col-widths">
              <th>Date/Time</th>
              <th>Home Team</th>
              <th>Away Team</th>
              <th>Home Goals</th>
              <th>Away Goals</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {fixtures.api.fixtures.map(fixture => (
              <tr key={fixture.fixture_id}>
                <td>{fixture.event_date}</td>
                <td>{fixture.homeTeam.team_name}</td>
                <td>{fixture.awayTeam.team_name}</td>
                <td>
                  <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="homeGoals">
                      <StyledInput
                        size="sm"
                        required
                        type="text"
                        defaultValue={fixture.goalsHomeTeam}
                        className="smaller-input"
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Form>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="awayGoals">
                      <StyledInput
                        size="sm"
                        required
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="-"
                        defaultValue={fixture.goalsAwayTeam}
                        className="smaller-input"
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Form>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </GridWrapper>
  );
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fixtures' of undefined
```

How do I access the data within the `fixtures` array in the Json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a new feature called Optional Chaining in JavaScript to solve this problem.
[Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for more information on Optional Chaining.

```
{fixtures?.api?.fixtures?.length ?
  fixtures.api.fixtures.map(fixture => (
     <div className="fixture">
      {fixture}
     </div>
)):null}
```

Essentially, this optional chaining ***?.*** is an error-proof way to access nested object properties, even if an intermediate property doesn’t exist.

Comment: Thanks for this Ashish!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the fixtures variable has data and then do check if the keys belongs to data or not and at last if the fixtures do hold an array to map -

```
{fixtures && fixtures.api && fixtures.api.fixtures.length ?
              fixtures.api.fixtures.map(fixture => (
          )):null}
```